# DocumentDb cannot handle hyphen (-) in column names

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I am saving this following XML to DocumentDB:

```
<DocumentDbTest_Countries> 
  <country>C25103657983</country> 
  <language>C25103657983</language> 
  <countryCode>383388823</countryCode>
  <version>2015-08-25T08:36:59:982.3552</version>
  <integrity>
     <hash-algorithm>sha1</hash-algorithm>
     <hash /> 
  </integrity>
  <context-info> 
     <created-by>unittestuser</created-by> 
     <created-on>2015/08/25 08:36:59</created-on> 
     <created-time-zone>UTC</created-time-zone> 
     <modified-by>unittestuser</modified-by>
     <modified-on>2015/08/25 08:36:59</modified-on> 
     <modified-time-zone>UTC</modified-time-zone>
  </context-info>
</DocumentDbTest_Countries>
```

Which gets saved fine to the DocumentDB as following:

```
{
"DocumentDbTest_Countries": {
"integrity": {
   "hash-algorithm": "sha1",
   "hash": ""
  },
"context-info": {
  "created-by": "unittestuser",
  "created-on": "2015/08/25 08:36:59",
  "created-time-zone": "UTC",
  "modified-by": "unittestuser",
  "modified-on": "2015/08/25 08:36:59",
  "modified-time-zone": "UTC"
},
"country": "C25103657983",
"language": "C25103657983",
"countryCode": 383388823,
"version": "2015-08-25T08:36:59:982.3552"
},
"id": "f917945d-eaee-4eff-944d-dae366de7be1"
}
```

As you can see the column name is indeed saved with hyphen (-) in it in the DocumentDB (without any kind of errors/exceptions/warning apparently) but then when I try to do a lookup it fails in the *Query Explorer*. It seems there is no way to search on hyphenated column names. Is this true? or, am I missing something? Can someone please point me to a documentation about this limitation somewhere??

Comment: did you try replacing hyphen with underscore in your query?

Comment: @Luca, sure I can do that, I can also just remove the hyphen. But that's beyond the point here. 

This data is existing data which is stored is Sql Server (as Xml) and is also query able as is. 
So the reader also expects the data with a hypehen (-) in it. Now I have change the reader code also has to be updated which I don't want to do unless extremely required. :)
Also, I expected some documentation about this limitation/restriction from MSDN and then think of workarounds.

Comment: Deb, did my answer below do the trick for you? If so, can you please accept my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the trick was to use **CollectionName.DocumentName** instead of just the **DocumentName**, like this (thanks to @Laan for pointing me in that direction) :):

```
SELECT * FROM TestProject.DocumentDbTest_Countries c where c["@country"] = "C26092630539"
```

[image: Proof image]

But then I still miss the Document.Id and Document.SelfLink data in the return Document data.

Comment: Well, of course you miss it - the `id` is not a part of `DocumentDbTest_Countries`, it's part of its parent (the `TestProject` item in this case). Apparently, your object is a payload of the real collection item, and the real collection item has the metadata like the ID. If you need the ID, just get `from TestProject`.

Comment: @Luaan I don't understand and I don't agree :)

Indeed this  DocumentDbTest_Countries is part of a Collection and is not a **Document-inside-Document** so it has its own **Id** and **SelfLink** like for every other saved Document inside that collection - so i do expect the Id and SelfLink, which I get just fine when I do a SELECT * FROM DocumentDbTest_Countries c (i.e., without the collection name). [See proof](http://i.imgur.com/ziqVgrB.png)

Answer (score 8):

For field names that use certain characters (space, "@", "-", etc.) or which conflict with SQL keywords, you have to use quoted property accessor syntax. So instead of writing:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.context-info.created-by = "unittestuser"
```

write:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c["context-info"]["created-by"] = "unittestuser"
```

Comment: Hey @Larry, thanks for your reply.
I have already tried this already but it does not work. 

For proof please check this [image](http://i.imgur.com/rTqkEOT.png)

Comment: Deb, I think I see your issue. In your query3, you leave out the DocumentDbTest_Countries part of the query. That line should read: `string query3 = "SELECT * FROM DocumentDbTest_Countries c WHERE c[\"DocumentDbTest_Countries\"][\"@country\"] = \"C260`...

Answer (score 4):

> You can also access properties using the quoted property operator []. For example, SELECT c.grade and SELECT c["grade"] are equivalent. This syntax is useful when you need to escape a property that contains spaces, special characters, or happens to share the same name as a SQL keyword or reserved word.

`-` is one of those special characters, so to access a property which contains `-`, you need to use the quoted property operator. It *is* documented :)

Of course, the idiomatic way would be to use camel casing instead of hyphens, but if you don't want to change your structures, you'll need to use the quoted properties.

For example, using your test data, this query works:

```
SELECT c["country-code"] FROM root.DocumentDbTest_Countries c
```

**EDIT:**

The syntax of the query is a bit confusing, which is what led to most of your problems. Contrary to what you might think,

```
select * from DocumentDbTest_Countries
```

*doesn't* in fact mean "get me all the data in `DocumentDbTest_Countries`". Instead, it seems to mean "get me all the data in the current collection, and alias it as `DocumentDbTest_Countries`". This is obvious when you look at the data returned - you'd expect it to return only the fields inside of `DocumentDbTest_Countries`, but it actually returns all of the values, including the `id` (which is *not* a part of `DocumentDbTest_Countries` - should have been obvious earlier :D).

I don't understand why it's designed as this (even using `DocumentDbTest_Countries c` to explicitly specify an alias doesn't select `DocumentDbTest_Countries`), but the fix is to actually start the identifier with the collection name. `root` is just a way to refer to "this collection", so

```
select * from root.DocumentDbTest_Countries
```

returns what you'd expect from the original query. Unless you figure out why the original query behaves the way it does, I'd stick with explicitly using `root` (or a collection name) as the root every time. It seems to me that using `from whatever` will always return the current collection, unless you have a collection named `whatever` - a weird design decision, if you ask me. This means that unless you have a collection named `lotsOfFun`, the following works the same as using `root`:

```
select * from lotsOfFun.DocumentDbTest_Countries
```

Maybe it's because the top-level object is not named, so they decided that whatever name will work just as well, but that's just an idea.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already tried the c[country-code] way but that also does not work. The documented quoted property operator that you are talking about doesn't also tell anything about [the hyphen](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-sql-query/). [Proof - check image](http://i.imgur.com/XbTtaah.png?1)

Comment: @Deb The quotes are important. It must be `c["country-code"]`, not `c[country-code]`. The latter would work with MS SQL, of course, but this isn't MS SQL.

Comment: I tried c["country-code"] also - but that also does not work. 
Did you have an working example of the c["country-code"] maybe??

Comment: `country-code` may be a bad example because your sample has `countryCode` as the field name. For that, just use `c.countryCode`. For `created-by`, use `c["created-by"]`.

Comment: Correction: For `context-info.created-by`, use `c["context-info"]["created-by"]`.

Comment: @Deb Using the same test data you have, `SELECT c.DocumentDbTest_Countries["country-code"] FROM c` works fine for me. `SELECT c["country-code"] FROM root.DocumentDbTest_Countries c` also works as expected. It also works when used in a `where` - see http://i.imgur.com/IHEsqeF.png?1  Are you *sure* you tried with `c["country-code"]`?

Comment: @Luaan, I need to load a Document based on search criteria so only select does not work for me. Please check [this proof](http://i.imgur.com/0f7Kybq.png) of what I tried so far.

Comment: Aha, thanks!!!!  
I see now. You used a trick word "root". 
I now tested with the name of my collection.document and the where condition then it works. :) 

SELECT * FROM TestProject.DocumentDbTest_AllFieldTypes c
where c["rich-text"] != "" 
[Proof image](http://i.imgur.com/INefx0f.png)

Comment: @Deb Wait a minute, `SingleOrDefault`? Didn't you mean `FirstOrDefault`? The way your test is now, you're testing there's *exactly* one document with the given `context-info.created-by`. I assume your data has multiple such documents, so you get `null` back.

Comment: @Luaan don't worry about SingleOrDefault - I indeed expect a single record since I have a single record. :) 

It kind of works now with the "root" trick - but I don't get it at all!! :)
Also doing search by collectionName.documentName somehow does not return the main document with its Id and SelfLink, just a document. :(

Comment: @Deb I've added information about that to my answer. It's technically a whole different question, but...

Comment: Thanks @Luaan, I also added a answer about it now to the question.
Indeed, its a fun new world with DocumentDB... :P